# Yii и повторная отправка формы

Tags: php, yii

У нас есть `site.com/index.php?r=controller/index`, форма с полями с названиями `filters[...]` Отправляем форму и при обновлении стр. каждый раз опять отправка формы.
Не пойму куда впихнуть стандартное решение данной проблемы. `(header(..); exit();)`

Если в контроллер (серверная обработка страницы), то там уже предусмотрено перенаправление `$this->render('index');` на представление  (страница пользователя - index.php). Ведь когда даже используешь header() на страницу, то всегда сначала работает серверная часть перед загрузкой пользовательской...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем ясно что вы пытаетесь сделать, если хотите предотвратить повторную отправку формы, попробуйте после удачного сохранения формы перенаправить пользователя а не показать страницу:

```
if($model->save()){
    $this->redirect('site/login');
}else{
    $this->render('index',[...]);
}
```

Так же посмотрите метод [CController::refresh-detail()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#refresh-detail), вы можете после валидации сбросить форму:

```
if($model->save()){
    $this->refresh();
}else{
    $this->render('index',[...]);
}
```